# Should all public methods be declared in the interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface

Given an interface like:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
}
```

And a class that implements it like:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar()
    {
        returns "Bar";
    }

    public string SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        returns "Something else";
    }
}
```

Is there a problem with this code? Should we add all methods to the interface?

One example: imagine a private method that grows complex enough to need unit tests. Could you make it public (so it can be called from the test project) but not add it to the interface (because no clients need to call it)?

Comment: **Thought experiment:**  Classes are free to implement *more than one interface, or no interfaces at all.*  If my class implements no interfaces, does that make the class unusable?

Comment: `Could you make it public (so it can be called from the test project) but not add it to the interface (because no clients need to call it)?` -- **Yes.**

Comment: Tons of classes implement `IDisposable`. If the only public method they had was `Dispose` they wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: I usually make private methods I want to test internal, not public

Comment: Hand in hand with what Robert is saying is the I in SOLID for interface segregation: https://codeburst.io/understanding-solid-principles-interface-segregation-principle-b2d57026cf6c

Comment: Testing methods that a normal program can never call is a pretty slippery slope.  That doesn't have much to do with testing, everything to do with "where is the bug" diagnostics.  You use a debugger for that, it doesn't mind you setting a breakpoint on a private or internal method.  The unit test is an excellent way to trigger that breakpoint, be sure you're comfortable about using a debugger in a unit test.

Comment: Unit tests should not target private methods as private methods are implementation details and therefor should be free to be refactored even without any public change to your class. You should test private members only via the public members that use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what a class does is simple enough that we can test its public methods and private methods at the same time, then we can just test the public methods.

If the private method grows so complex that between the public and private method we need too many combinations of tests then it's time to separate the private method into its own class. Making the private method public would break the encapsulation of the class. Even if we don't add the method to an `interface`, making the class method public still adds the method to the public interface *of the class itself*.

So if we have this:

```
public class ClassWithComplexPrivateMethod
{

    public void DoSomething(int value)
    {
        PrivateMethodThatNeedsItsOwnTests(value);
    }

    private string PrivateMethodThatNeedsItsOwnTests(int value)
    {
        // This method has gotten really complicated!
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

We might refactor to something like this:

```
public interface IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid
{
    string MethodThatNeedsItsOwnTests(int value);
} 

public class RefactoredClass
{
    private readonly IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid _dependency;

    public RefactoredClass(IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string DoSomething(int value)
    {
        return _dependency.MethodThatNeedsItsOwnTests(value);
    }
}
```

And now a new class implements `IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid`.

Now when we test the refactored class we mock `IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid`, and we write separate unit tests for any classes that implement `IRepresentsWhatThePrivateMethodDid`.

It may seem like a contradiction to say that exposing the private method as public breaks encapsulation, but exposing it as its own separate class doesn't. There are two differences:

- The refactored class doesn't depend on the new class containing what used to be the private method. It depends on the new interface.
- The interaction between the refactored class and the interface is still hidden within its methods. Other classes that call its public methods don't "know" about how it uses its dependency. (In fact, other classes will likely depend on abstractions instead of directly on the refactored class.)

---

It's also easy to get carried away with this and introduce the separate dependency too soon, when we could have tested the class - including its private methods - through the public methods. I've done this lots of times, and it can result in lots and lots of unnecessary interfaces and extra classes. There's no perfection, just our best efforts to balance it.

---

One more thought: We tend to use interfaces to represent dependencies, but we don't have to. If what we're extracting was just a single private method, then perhaps we can represent it with a delegate or a `Func` instead, like this:

```
public class RefactoredClass
{
    private readonly Func<int, string> _dependency;

    public RefactoredClass(Func<int, string> dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string DoSomething(int value)
    {
        return _dependency(value);
    }
}
```

Or we can use a delegate, which I like better than `Func` because it indicates what the function does.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when a class implements an interface all members of an interface must be implemented, it does not go the other way around.

Also when implementing an interface member, the corresponding member of the implementing class must be public, non-static, and have the same name and parameter signature as the interface member. You can have methods, even public, in the class that are not defined in the interface.

On top of that, the interface itself provides no functionality that a class or struct can inherit in the way that it can inherit base class functionality. However, if a base class implements an interface, any class that's derived from the base class inherits that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Interface should represent just the required API without regard to unit-testing and smth else.

---

To test *public*-methods of class you should do *nothing* because Test-project has access to them. You just need to instantiate a class and inject all required dependency using Mock.

[Example: testing class without any dependencies](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-nunit/PrimeService.Tests/PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.cs)

[Example: testing class with dependency](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Mock-Library-f7af332b)

---

To test private methods of a class need to make them visible to test-project:

- mark *private* methods as [internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)
- make internal-method visible to test-project: add to *AssemblyInfo.cs* the directive *[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Project.Tests")]* (see [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8))